# c# UDPClient.Receive randomly not receiving packets

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

I have a .net Framework 4.8 program that on a background worker constantly reads udp packets send by an arduino on a windows hosted wifi network.
After updating to windows 10 1909 from 1809, the program randomly stops working.

I installed wireshark to check if i was receiving any data at all, there is a constant flow of UPD packets to port 10001 from the arduino IP, but the program is stuck at udpclient.receive without any exception thrown.

This is the code of the background worker:

```
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(10001);
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.137.4"), 10001);
        byte[] receiveBytes;
        ardunoPacketTimer.Start();
        try
        {
            while (worker.CancellationPending == false)
            {
                receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                //When whatever is going wrong happens, the program doesn't get past here
                SendArduinoData2Joystick(receiveBytes);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this .NET Framework? .NET Core? What version? This is important info you need to provide for us to be able to assist.

Comment: I am using .net Framework 4.8, sorry for missing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows firewall it was, disabling it solved the problem.
It is weird because it wasn't always blocking the traffic, but since we disabled the windows firewall on the hosted network everything is going fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a catch statement with some logging, so you do not just discard the exception which is probably occurring.

Comment: There is no exception, the program is stuck at the receive line but no exception is raised